# How to speed up the comparision of 2 collections in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro that gets a collection of collection and than takes two of the collections and gives me the similarity.
Now if I compare the two collections with a simple for loop it will take hours to compare all 854 collection that are contained in pCol.
Here is my code:

```vb
    Function CompareCollections(ByVal pCol As Collection) As Collection
    Dim outer As Long
    Dim inner As Long
    'collections that will be compared to each other
    Dim inCol As Collection
    Dim outCol As Collection
    'collection used for return values
    Dim retCol As Collection
    'result of single comparison
    Dim res As CompResult
    'comparison variables
    Dim iIdx As Long
    Dim oIdx As Long
    Dim same As Long

    Set retCol = New Collection
    For outer = 1 To pCol.Count - 1
        Set outCol = pCol(outer)
        For inner = outer + 1 To pCol.Count
            Set inCol = pCol(inner)

            Set res = New CompResult
            res.LeftTable = outCol(1) 'index 1 contains a header
            res.RightTable = inCol(1)

            'compare the two collections <== PART I WANT TO SPEED UP
            same = 0
            For oIdx = 2 To outCol.Count 'starting with 2 to ignore the header
                For iIdx = 2 To inCol.Count
                    If inCol(iIdx) = outCol(oIdx) Then same = same + 1
                Next iIdx
                DoEvents
            Next oIdx
            res.Result1 = same / (outCol.Count - 1)
            res.Result2 = same / (inCol.Count - 1)
            retCol.Add res

            Set res = Nothing
            Set inCol = Nothing
            DoEvents
        Next inner
        Set outCol = Nothing
        DoEvents
    Next outer
    Set CompareCollections = retCol
End Function
```

I really hope you guys can help me.

**EDIT:**
The CompResult class is a simple structure, because I could not add a custom type to the collection:

```
Private mLeftTable As String
Private mRightTable As String
Private mResult1 As Double
Private mResult2 As Double

Public Property Get LeftTable() As String
    LeftTable = mLeftTable
End Property

Public Property Let LeftTable(value As String)
    mLeftTable = value
End Property

Public Property Get RightTable() As String
    RightTable = mRightTable
End Property

Public Property Let RightTable(value As String)
    mRightTable = value
End Property

Public Property Get Result1() As Double
    Result = mResult1
End Property

Public Property Let Result1(value As Double)
    mResult1 = value
End Property

Public Property Get Result2() As Double
    Result = mResult2
End Property

Public Property Let Result2(value As Double)
    mResult2 = value
End Property
```

Comment: Please, could you post the CompResult class?

Comment: Use an `ArrayLlist` instead - then you can use the `.Contains()` method. Alternatively use a `Dictionary` class and use `.Exists()` to see if there's a match. Note that a Dictionary must contain unique keys whereas an ArrayList does not.

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks for the tip. It really makes it a whole lot faster. Now I only have to find a fast way to write my gigantic collection (>300k elements) into a excel sheet

Comment: @TimvdBerg use the `.ToArray()` method and then use `Range.Resize()` to write it all in one go.

Comment: @MacroMan Thanks. .ToArray()  works like a charm. To only problem is that the resize alone does not help me to write it in one go. The reason for this is that I have a nested array insted of a 2D array. Do you know a trick how I can make this work?

Comment: @TimvdBerg Only thing I can think of is looping through the "parent" array object and repeating the action - not ideal but still faster than looping through a range...

Answer (score 0):

A first tip: try to precalculate outCol.Count, inCol.Count and pCol.Count in order to avoid unnecessary calculations.

Second tip: if in your object CompResult the res.Result1  and res.Result2 are integers, use "\" instead of "/".

Third tip: try to use integers instead of long values wherever you can.

Fourth tip: try to replace for loops by a "for each" loops when looping for every column. It seems a little faster.

A last tip might be transform collections (ranges) in arrays and iterate through them, as it seems faster than iterate through ranges.